What is the purpose of the resistor and capacitor connected across the inputs of the op-amp transimpedance circuit?

I saw this circuit on a meteorological device. Why is a resistor + capacitor across the op-amp inputs?

Can you edit the question to include a link to the source of the schematic.

We really need to know the specific application of the circuit. If the loop antenna is detecting lightning strikes, the RC circuit could be nothing more than ESD protection, dumping energy when it ramps up too much, too fast. What is the "meteorological device?"

A resistor capacitor network at the input of a transimpedance amplifier is one way to improve stability. I would have expected the capacitor to be much lower in value though.
It works by reducing the loop gain at high frequencies where phase shift round the feedback loop would cause instability (especially with an inductive input source).
You say "Meterological Device" what is the application? What is the function of that part of the circuit?

In addition to the response from @Kevin, the additional path also helps maintain a decent impedance matching at higher frequencies. As the loop gain starts dropping, the input resistance starts rising. The additional path counteracts that effect by introducing a parallel resistance, extending the matching bandwidth at the input.
